# WPF error CS0433

Tags: .net, wpf, sgen

I'm getting this error in my WPF application. I get this error not always. If I make Clean and then Rebuild everything is ok.

```
SGEN (0,0):                                             
error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

SGEN (0,0):
errorCS0433: The type 'XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper' exists in both 'library1.dll' and 'library2.dll'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [RummageTypeRenamer](http://www.aldaray.com/Rummage/Doc/RummageTypeRenamer), a free tool bundled with our obfuscator Rummage (I work for Aldaray), to rename the `GeneratedInternalTypeHelper` type to something else.

We rename it to something like `GeneratedInternalTypeHelper$(ProjectName)` so that it is unique across projects and never clashes. We do that in all our build scripts [to get ILMerge to work](http://roman.st/Article/ILMerge-and-XamlGeneratedNamespaceGeneratedInternalTypeHelper) (blog entry in my colleague’s private blog).

Comment: Worked for me. I put it in post-build like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19436532/2772330).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Bugs) by Scott Hanselman discussing this issue for WPF.

Other people that have had this problem have fixed it by installing some hotfixes.  Check out [this article](http://www.manning-sandbox.com/message.jspa?messageID=37581) for more information.

If you're using Citrix, you might want to [check this out](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX112939).  You could have a permissions issue.  This particular article deals with an ASP .NET application, but you might have a similar issue in your WPF application.  It's a good place to start.

Comment: I don't use Citrix. Not sure whether it because of hotfixes provided in mentioned article. I got this error only today. It worked perfect for several month.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the persistent compiled XML serialization assembly generator. It generates classes from XML serializable types. If you don't use this, you can uncheck this in project properties.

Comment: In one project I don't use XML serialization assembly generator so I disable it. It helped. But I'm still curious why it happened and how to fix it if I would need to run sgen in both projects.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure out why I've got this generated class *XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper* in my library. MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xamlgeneratednamespace.generatedinternaltypehelper.aspx) nothing helpful:

> A class generated by the workflow
>   designer used to generate CLR types
>   for XAML documents.

But I found the line of code which causes generation of this class:

```
<Grid DataContext="{TemplateBinding InternalDataContext}">
```

I replaced it with "runtime equivalent":

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding InternalDataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

Maybe it may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the XmlSerializer's generated code in c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\
after running your application, it'll be something.cs.
Mine was: "me2ywucq.0.cs", just text search for your Type name inside it's code.

You can also change the path it writes the code to when it creates assemblies at runtime
see [Changing where XmlSerializer Outputs Temporary Assemblies by scott](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ChangingWhereXmlSerializerOutputsTemporaryAssemblies.aspx)

Add the following to your app.config or web.config:

```
<system.xml.serialization> 
  <xmlSerializer tempFilesLocation="c:\\foo"/> 
</system.xml.serialization>
```

After finding the code you can compile it yourself into an myAssembly.XmlSerializers.dll or implement IXmlSerializer in your code, without breaking compatibility with prev serializations.