# Visual Studio Post Build does not like my conditional

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2012, post-build-event

I have a post build conditional that looks like this:

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release
(
    echo Update $(TargetName) to be non conflicting
    "$(SolutionDir)ILMerge\RummageTypeRenamer.exe" -f XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper -t XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper$(TargetName) $(TargetName).dll
    del $(TargetName).dll
    ren $(TargetName).Runmage.dll $(TargetName).dll
)
```

This runs fine if I take off the condition and the parens.  But if I run it as is, I get the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The whole statement then prints out, and the conditional looks good:

> if Release==Release

Why doesn't Visual Studio like my conditional?

Comment: batch expected the parenthesis on the same line as the `IF`

Comment: (+1) for showing how to use RummageTypeRenamer in post-build :). I know that this is out of the scope of the topic, but still people are able to search this with "RummageTypeRenamer post-build" search string. Why did you need this assembly only for Release mode? Why not Debug? If you want i can ask a separate question and notify here. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreyK. - sorry to say that I don't recall why I needed this.

Answer (score 2):

found the solution here:
[How to run Visual Studio post-build events for debug build only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150053/how-to-run-visual-studio-post-build-events-for-debug-build-only/13874593#13874593) (see this comment:
I've found that the entire command needs to be on one line or you'll get "exited with code 255" )

So your post build should look like:

```
    if $(ConfigurationName)==Release goto _release

    goto _exit

    :_release

    echo Update $(TargetName) to be non conflicting
    "$(SolutionDir)ILMerge\RummageTypeRenamer.exe" -f XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper -t XamlGeneratedNamespace.GeneratedInternalTypeHelper$(TargetName) $(TargetName).dll
    del $(TargetName).dll
    ren $(TargetName).Runmage.dll $(TargetName).dll

    :_exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the K&R style parens:

```
if $(ConfigurationName)==Release (
    echo Update $(TargetName) to be non conflicting
    ...
)
```